# IF-statement doesn't work in jQuery callback function of click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some `<div>` and its `padding-left` have to be modified when **left** or **right** button is clicked. I want change `font-weight` and `font-style` according to the `padding-left` of each selected element.
If `padding-left` is 20, the `font-weight` will be set with `normal`. And its `font-style` will be assigned with `italic` when `padding-left` is 40.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".toGrab").on("click", function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
            $("#key").click(function () {
                var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
                $(".selected").css({
                    paddingLeft: "+=" + "20"
                });
                if (sl >= '100') {
                    $(".selected").css({
                        paddingLeft: 100
                    });
                }
            });
            $("#key1").click(function () {
                $(".selected").css({
                    paddingLeft: "-=" + "20"
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#key").click(function () {
                  
                    var n = $(".toGrab").css("padding-left");

                    if (n < 20) {
                        $(".toGrab").css("font-weight", "normal"); alert("n");
                    }
                    if (n < 40) {
                        $(".toGrab").css("font-weight", "italic"); alert("n");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".toGrab").css("font-weight", "bold");
                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
        div{
            background-color:yellow;
            margin-top:20px;
        }
        div {

}
.selected {
 background-color:lightblue;
 
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="key">left</button>
    <button id="key1">right</button>

    
    <div class='toGrab'>grand parent</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>parent</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
```

the padding-left changes when select the div and click the left button

Comment: Try `sl >= 100` instead of `sl >= '100'`.

Comment: @xufox that if function is working.the if function used in  last step for changing the font weight is not working

Comment: Still, comparing something to a string as if it is a number is not intuitive and can lead to unexpected results… for the `if` statements below, you need to know what `n` is. It’s a string with `px` at the end. You can’t compare that to a number. You need to remove `px` and convert `n` to a number first.

Comment: Your first if will never work. When n<20 than n<40 is also valid. You need to change your second if into else if.

Comment: @xufox i convert n to a px value but its not working.the main problem is the value is not enter into the inside the if function. it directly goes to the else function

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestion and revised codes as following for you.

1. `italic` belongs to `font-style` instead of `font-weight`.
2. Why it doesn't work changing CSS styles is that you override `$("#key").click(function(){ // Here })` and did not give the same code in `$("#key1").click(function(){ // Here })`
3. `$(".toGrab")` returns an Array of matched jQuery elements so that you have to execute `$(".toGrab").each(function(){ // $(this) will be the each element of the Array. })`.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".toGrab").on("click", function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
            $("#key").click(function () {
                var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
                sl = sl >= 100 ? "100" : "+=20";
                $(".selected").css({
                    "padding-left": sl
                });
                $(".toGrab.selected").each(function() {
                    var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                    var isPaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 20;
                    var isPaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 40;
                    if(isPaddingLeft20) $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
                    else if(isPaddingLeft40) $(this).css("font-style", "italic"); 
                    else $(this).css("font-weight", "bold"); 
                });
            });
            $("#key1").click(function () {
                $(".selected").css({
                    "padding-left": "-=" + "20"
                });
                $(".toGrab.selected").each(function() {
                    var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                    var isPaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 20;
                    var isPaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 40;
                    if(isPaddingLeft20) $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
                    else if(isPaddingLeft40) $(this).css("font-style", "italic"); 
                    else $(this).css("font-weight", "bold"); 
                });
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<style>
        div{
            background-color:yellow;
            margin-top:20px;
        }
        div {

}
.selected {
 background-color:lightblue;
 
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="key">left</button>
    <button id="key1">right</button>

    
    <div class='toGrab'>grand parent</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>parent</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
```